# Load referenced data types from custom Identity UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-identity

I have a custom `IdentityUser` called `ApplicationUser`:

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<Board> Boards { get; set; }
}
```

When loading a user with `_userManager.GetUserAsync(User)` in a handler method, it loads an ApplicationUser but without the `Boards` collection.
When working directly with an `DbContext`, I would use `_context.User.Include(u => u.Boards)` but this isn't possible with the `UserManager`?

How do I solve this issue?

---

My `ApplicationDbContext` currently looks like this:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```